# selenium click not working on element with onclick="" and bound event listener

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, onclick

I am using Selenium driver to  automatically display webpages from StackOverflow. I want all the comments to be displayed in the browser, so I have code to find the elements at the bottom of the comments lists that are like this:

`<a class="js-show-link comments-link " title="expand to show all comments on this post" href="#" onclick="">show <b>7</b> more comments</a>`

Once I locate this element, I try a `.click()` method on it, but nothing happens until about the third click.

(One more thing: after I posted the question, I realize that the `.click()` method works if I employ it **after I manually click on the link**, and I reload the page. This is strange. Maybe the page needs to be in the cache?)

This used to work fine a few months ago, but now there is an *event listener* (a little dark icon with the letters "ev" in it) right next to this element, and the `onclick` attribute is an empty string.

Would the event listening bind affect the behavior of `.click()`? Is there a solution? Thanks.

I am using selenium in Python 2.7. Here is my code:

```
link = u'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication'
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
driver.get(link)
myelement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[title="expand to show all comments on this post"]')
myelement.click()
```

Comment: You could try clicking that `icon` you mentioned instead... Or the element that contains both the icon and your "show more comments" link. (I'm guessing at how the `html` is structured here, so there might not be something that contains both of those).